# Twisted callback loop blocking further data from being recieved

Tags: python, callback, twisted, deferred

When a callback loop is running in Twisted, it was my impression that the reactor was still able to send/receive data from the server, as it was able to function 'between' the callbacks. However, when I run the script below, it entirely ignores the `self.transport.write()` line. The server is just the basic echo server Twisted have on their website.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred


class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):

    deferred = Deferred()

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.deferred.addCallback(self.doThing)
        self.deferred.callback(0)

    def doThing(self, _):
        print 'xxx'
        self.transport.write('Hello, world!')
        self.deferred.addCallback(self.doThing)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        print "Server said:", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()


class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):

    protocol = EchoClient


def main():
    f = EchoFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP('192.168.0.7', 8000, f) # Correctly connected to my server
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expected one, or even a few, 'xxx's being printed, then the server sending an echo of 'Hello, world!' back to me, then more 'xxx's. What I get instead is an infinite scrolling of 'xxx's and no attempt at even sending the 'Hello, world!' to the server. What am I missing/misunderstanding?

Comment: You should really be using [endpoints](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/endpoints.html) rather than calling `connectTCP` directly.

Comment: Also, `deferred = Deferred()` instantiates a single `Deferred` instance shared between all instances of `EchoClient`, which is an anti-pattern.  You should be initializing `self.deferred` as the first line of `connectionMade`.

Comment: Also consider using [react](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.react.html) rather than running the reactor directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your example is never letting the main loop run.

When a connection is established, you add a callback to `self.deferred` - I'm not sure what operation `self.deferred` is supposed to represent, but apparently nothing useful.

Then you immediately (synchronously) call back `self.deferred`.  This goes right away to execute `doThing`, which calls `self.transport.write`.  This adds some bytes to the outgoing buffer to be sent when the mainloop next runs.  Then, in that callback, you immediately (synchronously) add another callback to `self.deferred` which will run as soon as the current callback is completed.  So we go into `doThing`, which calls `self.transport.write`.  We still haven't written anything yet, let alone read anything to deliver to `dataReceived`, because we haven't made it back to the main loop.  But we add another callback to that `Deferred`.  Which calls `doThing` again.

This keeps going forever, allocating an infinite amount of memory on the transport as you buffer an ever-increasing amount of outgoing traffic, but never allow the program to return from `connectionMade`, make it back to the main loop, and wait for writability and readability events.

I don't know how to fix this program because it's not clear what it is that you're *trying* to do, but whatever it is, this isn't how :).

Comment: Are you saying the main reactor is blocked until the callback chain its executing finishes? I was under the impression that the reactor "regains control" after each individual callback/errback (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: This was my impression too. Otherwise, why would you ever want you use deferreds over regular methods?

Comment: Deferreds are not integrated with the reactor at all.  You can in fact use Deferreds in programs entirely outside of Twisted, via https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deferred.  All a Deferred is, is a result which has not arrived yet; when you invoke the `.callback` method, the result is delievered and the callback chain executes. The reason you'd use a Deferred rather than a "regular method" is that if you have a function which returns a result later, a Deferred is a value it can *return* and allow its caller to pass back.

Comment: If you want something that will let you yield to the reactor loop, you can use the [`cooperate`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.1.0/api/twisted.internet.task.cooperate.html) API with a generator that yields periodically.